# Copy a specific part of a BYTE buffer to a structure+

Tags: c++, arrays, buffer, byte, memcpy

I was working in my file loader, and i decided it was better for the next updates instead of keep using fread and fseek read the hole file to a BYTE buffer, and so did i, now i was wondering if theres no easy way of assigning part of this BYTE buffer to an structure.

I Already tried making a temp buffer with the same size as the structure, copy all the BYTE i need from the original buffer to it, and use memcpy, but it didn't work right, i just received a lot of random numbers (which i think i am receiving their pointers, but i don't know right).

Thank you for your time!

**Edit: REAL Code**

```
void memread(BYTE from[],int pos, void * to,size_t size) 
{   
    BYTE * temp = new BYTE[sizeof(BYTE)*size];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i< 1+size; i++)
        temp[i] = from[i+pos];

    memcpy(to,temp,size);

}


... inside the file loader ...


fseek(fl,0,SEEK_END);
const int memory_size = (int)ftell(fl);


BYTE * memory = new BYTE[sizeof(BYTE)*memory_size];
fseek(fl,0,SEEK_SET);

for (int i=1;i<=memory_size;i++)
fread(&memory[i],sizeof(BYTE),1,fl);

fclose(fl);

int memory_pos = 0;

XM::Memory xm;
memset(&xm,0,sizeof(XM::Memory));


memread(memory,1,&xm.Header,sizeof(XM::Header));
```

Comment: **EDIT** Found the error, the error was in the memread function, now I've fixed it, sorry for anything! I Fixed the code if anyone is interested!

Comment: BTW: Is this the famous Fast Tracker XM format you are trying to read?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes, i am trying to make a full c++ open source player library for the XM, MOD and IT format, long life to the Chiptune! I Think next week is ready, the pattern/channel/row loading is finished, all i need to finish is the sample/instrument loading play rate and choose which library use to play, i was thinking about WINMM or OPENAL, but i am not sure...

Comment: Don't want to ruin your party, but [Audiere](http://audiere.sourceforge.net/home.php) is an LGPL project, doing just that and more :) Also check the [DUMB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dumb/) open source tool (source of DUMB fileparsing is [here](http://dumb.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dumb/dumb/src/it/).

Comment: Well, the more the better, i am actually planning to make this to be used in demos and intros, and have *a perfect syncing system*, and make it portable, and fast and small... oh well i am doing this because i don't have anything to do at all LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are reading the file byte by byte, which will give you a bad performance. Next, your `memread` (where you don't free the temp buffer!) can be replaced by a simple `memcpy`

```
fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_END); 
const int memory_size = (int)ftell(fl); 

BYTE* memory = new BYTE[sizeof(BYTE) * memory_size];
fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_SET); 

fread(memory, sizeof(BYTE), memory_size, fl); 

fclose(fl); 

int memory_pos = 0; 

XM::Memory xm;
memset(&xm, 0, sizeof(XM::Memory)); 

memcpy(&xm.Header, memory + memory_pos, sizeof(XM::Header);
```

Never forget to `delete[]` your allocated arrays like `temp` and `memory`

Comment: Oh, really? Wow, i can't believe the answer was so easy! Thank you my friend, also, i have another question.

Comment: Inside my structure, i have some WORDS and DWORDS, using memcpy it will automatically transform the BYTES into WORDS and DWORDS?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to watch out for data alignment and endianness. You will have to tell your compiler that you want the structure to be byte aligned, otherwise you will run into trouble. If f.e. the file is big-endian, and you are reading it as little-endian, all the bytes in a WORD or DWORD will have to be swapped.

Comment: If you're using the MS compiler you can use the [pack pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help, now everything is working fine, i still can't understant the pack pragma, but i after i will read more about it :)

Comment: Well say alignment is set to 4 bytes. And you have a struct with a BYTE and a DWORD, the size of the struct will be 8 because the compiler aligns the DWORD on a 4 byte boundary. Therefore if you copy data from a file to the struct, 3 bytes will be lost (if the file has sequential data). In that case, you should set the alignment to 1. It really depends on how the file is saved.